# Failing to send a testnet transaction manually

Tags: testnet

I use [Ken Shirriff's post](http://www.righto.com/2014/02/bitcoins-hard-way-using-raw-bitcoin.html) on how to manually create and send a transaction, and I tried to adjust it to work with testnet.
AFAIK after adjusting to the testnet addresses, no further adjustments should be made in the tx creation and signature process.

However, my transaction does not work...

I successfully connect to peer `185.28.76.179:18333`, send the transaction but nothing happens.
What should I do to figure this out?

Here is the raw tx:

```
010000000142ad1ac9d0214d326a9f5f4e0051bb6f0e197bb7bf0661266623f865a1a38d10000000008b4830450221008e434d7e6e0dc3741d99142b1fdb3a6eeba7a6d1d1e95e1aa90dcb638fc17c7b0220179a9004bac06ac64914af1e9f29db3a7cb50942bf3e865a23727151f3bbd6330141047bc52c13eacc1adcb1eea06317760537947d67a9208351e4c213bed82f0ce843249c9675e5f28ca4b0848036118a43defa8b6c5d5d77250ac8709eca8f88e30bffffffff017b000000000000001976a9149437a39c0ddd64205002c3f9adda6bb77df1be8288ac00000000
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I use version 60002 of the protocol.

Comment: What do you mean by "nothing happens"? Do you not see the transaction on a block explorer? What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: I don't see the transaction on block explorers, do I guess it was dropped by the peer.